# Azure Blob Storage Informatica wirting behaviour

Tags: azure, blob

Hope you're fine. So I have a task to write some JSON files in AZURE BLOB STORAGE through Informatica BDM. I configured the target and everything seems to be ok except one thing. In Azure Blob Storage seems to store my target JSON files as a folder, and NOT as a JSON file, and inside that folder I can find a structure of files that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Fsb.png)

a lot of JSON files named part-0000X-tid.....JSON

is that correct behaviour of Azure Blob Storage or should I change something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, thats not supposed the way it owrks. If you upload one .json file the blob container should have that file with the given name and extension. Try to check for ContentType property in your code. CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = GetBlockBlob(blobName);
 blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/json";

Comment: I've checked and at contentType I have application/octet-stream

Comment: Try checking with the right contentType. Cannot help further sorry.